# How to save a specific column into an array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, read-data

I have a set of data in a .txt file that has an arbitrary number of columns, specified by the user in the input. I want to read that file, pick one of the columns and save it in an array. What is the best way to do this?

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40348550/store-a-txt-file-columns-into-an-array-in-c), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line-using-ifstream-in-c) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36673337/reading-text-file-and-storing-columns-in-an-array/36673540), but they all establish in the code the specific number of columns. I want it to be some input, so that the code is "general" and saves in that array the specific column from the input. Thank you!

EDIT: This is an example of how the input looks like - the total number of Columns (particles) is specified by the user. The output will be some other .txt of data coming from this one.

```
TIME     PART1       PART2       PART3       PART4  
0    0.0147496  934.902 0.0949583   -1192.37    0.0141576   950.604 0.0905118   -1074.44    
1.66667e-005    0.0147497   2804.7  0.0949583   -3577.12    0.0141576   2851.81 0.0905117   -3223.33    
3.33333e-005    0.0147497   4674.5  0.0949582   -5961.86    0.0141577   4753.02 0.0905116   -5372.21    
5e-005  0.0147498   6544.3  0.094958    -8346.6 0.0141578   6654.22 0.0905115   -7521.09    
6.66667e-005    0.01475 8414.09 0.0949578   -10731.3    0.0141579   8555.41 0.0905114   -9669.96
```

Comment: `specified by the user in the input` - show that, please.

Comment: It can be done in many ways. One could be a `cin >> col;`, and then I want the program to store the data of that specific column in some dynamical array.

Comment: I mean, show what the actual input and expected output will look like.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Just included.

Comment: not a duplicate, but it can help you a lot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c. Also the answers you link should help, to read a single column just read all and ignore all but the one you are interested in. Also note that it is not apparent why the q&as you link do not help to solve your issue. Adding a [mcve] of your attempt and explaining why it fails would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the user enters the coumn number over the console. So you can use the built-in cin function to read the input. You can use for loop and string streams to get the values. Code below; although you may have tweek it a little bit as per your needs

Edit: The code below has been edited a little bit. Now it should answer your question.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int n;
   cin >>n; //user needs to input the column number
   fstream newfile;
   //newfile.open("file.txt",ios::out);  // open the file to perform write operation using file object; Activate this function if you want to overwrite
   newfile.open("file.txt",ios::in); //open the file to perform read operation using file object
   if (newfile.is_open())
   {
      string line;
      getline(newfile, line); //skipping the first line
      while(getline(newfile, line))//loop throuhg rest of the lines
      { 
            int temp=n;
            while(temp != 0)//loop until you get to the requied column
            {
                getline(newfile, line, '\t'); //get the vaue separted by tab='\t'. Be sure that the last column also ends in '\t'
                temp--;
            }
            cout<<line<<endl; //now line holds the element on the loop-row of the selected column
      }
      newfile.close(); //close the file object.
   }
}
```

Comment: did you mean `while(temp--)` ? You are currently not using `temp`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I think you are right

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It seems it is what I needed, althought I am still adapting it to my code.